# React Testing Library - Context within onClick/onChange error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm looking for some assistance, I'm attempting to test a component within this test I'm testing an onChange handler within the component? If that makes sense I'm submitting the form this triggers the on change essentially, later it will also fire the onSubmit.
The issue is this function calls a dispatch function from my context.. I don't have that here and I assume I will need to mock this somehow? But for the life of me I cannot work this out.. I guess I am used to drilling down props and then you're able to obviously mock the prop fairly easily.

Any advice would be appreaciated I've included everything below the component, the test and the console error.
Please don't worry about my form missing certain text/copy, I removed it intentionally.

Component:

```
const HelpCards = () => {
  const { passwordModalState, passwordModalDispatch } = useContext(PasswordModalContext);
  const { formDisplayDispatch, formDisplayState } = useContext(FormDisplayContext);

  const { isOpen } = passwordModalState;
  const { form } = formDisplayState;

  const onFormChangeModalHandler = (formType) => {
    passwordModalDispatch({ type: 'CLOSE' });
    formDisplayDispatch({ type: formType });
  };

  const onLoginFormChange = () => {
    onFormChangeModalHandler('LOGIN');
  };

  const onRegistrationFormChange = () => {
    onFormChangeModalHandler('REGISTRATION');
  };

  return (
    <HelpContainer data-testid="helpContainer" modalDisplayed={isOpen}>
      {form === 'login' && (
        <Help data-testid="FirstTimeHereCard">
          <LaptopIcon alt="decorative laptop icon" />
          <HelpHeading>First time here?</HelpHeading>
          <HelpInfo></HelpInfo>
          <MarginVertical aria-hidden="true" remSize="3" />
          <HelpButton
            tabIndex="0"
            type="button"
            aria-label="register for online smart super access"
            onClick={onRegistrationFormChange}
            role="button"
          >
            Register for online access
          </HelpButton>
          <MarginVertical aria-hidden="true" remSize="3" />
        </Help>
      )}
      <Help data-testid="NeedSomeHelpCard">
        <PhoneIcon alt="decorative phone icon" />
        <HelpHeading>Need some Help ?</HelpHeading>
        <HelpInfo>
        </HelpInfo>
        <br />
        <HelpInfo>Having issues registering?</HelpInfo>
        <HelpInfo>
        </HelpInfo>
        <MarginVertical aria-hidden="true" remSize="3" />
        <HelpButton href={`tel:${}`} aria-label="">
          {}
        </HelpButton>
        <MarginVertical aria-hidden="true" remSize="3" />
      </Help>
      {form != 'login' && (
        <Help data-testid="AlreadyRegisteredCard">
          <CardIcon alt="decorative information card icon" />
          <HelpHeading>Already registered ?</HelpHeading>
          <MarginVertical aria-hidden="true" remSize="3" />
          <HelpButton
            role="button"
            type="button"
            data-testid="loginBtn"
            aria-label=""
            onClick={onLoginFormChange}
          >
            Log in
          </HelpButton>
          <MarginVertical aria-hidden="true" remSize="3" />
        </Help>
      )}
      <Help data-testid="">
        <CardIcon />
        <HelpHeading></HelpHeading>
        <MarginVertical aria-hidden="true" remSize="3" />
        <HelpButton data-testid="" href={} aria-label="
        </HelpButton>
        <MarginVertical aria-hidden="true" remSize="3" />
      </Help>
    </HelpContainer>
  );
};

export default HelpCards;
```

Test

```
test('', () => {
  const passwordModalContext = {
    passwordModalState: {
      isOpen: false
    }
  };

  const formContext = {
    formDisplayState: {
      form: 'login'
    }
  };

  const { container } = render(
    <FormDisplayContext.Provider value={formContext}>
      <PasswordModalContext.Provider value={passwordModalContext}>
        <HelpCards />
      </PasswordModalContext.Provider>
    </FormDisplayContext.Provider>
  );


  const button = screen.getByText(/register for online access/i);

  userEvent.click(button);

});
```

Error: (I know in the scope of my test this is failing because it does not exist.. I'm just unsure of the solution, mock? should I import it? and how to go about it?)

```
    TypeError: passwordModalDispatch is not a function

      88 |
      89 |   const onFormChangeModalHandler = (formType) => {
    > 90 |     passwordModalDispatch({ type: 'CLOSE' });
         |     ^
      91 |     formDisplayDispatch({ type: formType });
      92 |   };
      93 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use provided wrong value for `FormDisplayContext.Provider` it should be like this:

```
  const formContext = {
    passwordModalDispatch: jest.fn(), // <- missing this function
    formDisplayState: {
      form: 'login'
    }
  };

  const { container } = render(
    <FormDisplayContext.Provider value={formContext}>
      <PasswordModalContext.Provider value={passwordModalContext}>
        <HelpCards />
      </PasswordModalContext.Provider>
    </FormDisplayContext.Provider>
  );
```

Depend on how much you want to test, if you only want to test `HelpCards` in isolation (Unit Test), just give it a mock version of `passwordModalDispatch`.

But if you want to test its interaction (or integration test) with other Components then give its real implementation of `passwordModalDispatch`

Check out [this amazing article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/write-tests) to decide how you should test.

Comment: Thank you, this was a very direct/informative answer! 

I'll check out the article as well!